# Error update lg phoenix 2 to nougat 7.0

Tags: updates, 7.0-nougat, lg-phoenix-2

I want to ask how to update LG phoenix 2 to 7.0 nougat because my phone is 6.0 and I check update but it keep saying my phone is up to date while it not . Are att stop update it? And does you guy have anyway to update it manually ? P/s:I can't trust trash website to update so I came here !

Comment: See if this works: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=74939997&postcount=356

Comment: Usually companies stop sending updates after a few months since release. You may have to check for unofficial updates; risky.